# Cannot feed value of shape in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am attempting to train a CNN model following along with a tutorial, using the exact code specified and am receiving an error. Below is the code I am using.

```
# Common imports
from __future__ import division, print_function, unicode_literals
import numpy as np
import os
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image

from io import open
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior() 

# to make this notebook's output stable across runs
def reset_graph(seed=42):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    tf.set_random_seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)

# To plot pretty figures
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 14
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 12
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 12

# Where to save the figures
PROJECT_ROOT_DIR = "."
CHAPTER_ID = "cnn"

def save_fig(fig_id, tight_layout=True):
    path = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_DIR, "images", CHAPTER_ID, fig_id + ".png")
    print("Saving figure", fig_id)
    if tight_layout:
        plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(path, format='png', dpi=300)

#A couple utility functions to plot grayscale and RGB images:
def plot_image(image):
    plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray", interpolation="nearest")
    plt.axis("off")

def plot_color_image(image):
    plt.imshow(image.astype(np.uint8),interpolation="nearest")
    plt.axis("off")

#Convolutional Layer

china = load_sample_image("china.jpg")
flower = load_sample_image("flower.jpg")
image = china[150:220, 130:250]
height, width, channels = image.shape
image_grayscale = image.mean(axis=2).astype(np.float32)
images = image_grayscale.reshape(1, height, width, 1)

fmap = np.zeros(shape=(7, 7, 1, 2), dtype=np.float32)
fmap[:, 3, 0, 0] = 1
fmap[3, :, 0, 1] = 1
plot_image(fmap[:, :, 0, 0])
plt.show()
plot_image(fmap[:, :, 0, 1])
plt.show()

reset_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, height, width, 1))
feature_maps = tf.constant(fmap)
convolution = tf.nn.conv2d(X, feature_maps, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding="SAME")

with tf.Session() as sess:
    output = convolution.eval(feed_dict={X: images})

plot_image(images[0, :, :, 0])
save_fig("china_original", tight_layout=False)
plt.show()

plot_image(output[0, :, :, 0])
save_fig("china_vertical", tight_layout=False)
plt.show()

plot_image(output[0, :, :, 1])
save_fig("china_horizontal", tight_layout=False)
plt.show()


# Simple Example

# Load sample images
china = load_sample_image("china.jpg")
flower = load_sample_image("flower.jpg")
dataset = np.array([china, flower], dtype=np.float32)
batch_size, height, width, channels = dataset.shape

# Create 2 filters
filters = np.zeros(shape=(7, 7, channels, 2), dtype=np.float32)
filters[:, 3, :, 0] = 1  # vertical line
filters[3, :, :, 1] = 1  # horizontal line

# Create a graph with input X plus a convolutional layer applying the 2 filters
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, height, width, channels))
convolution = tf.nn.conv2d(X, filters, strides=[1,2,2,1], padding="SAME")

with tf.Session() as sess:
    output = sess.run(convolution, feed_dict={X: dataset})

plt.imshow(output[0, :, :, 1], cmap="gray") # plot 1st image's 2nd feature map
plt.show()

for image_index in (0, 1):
    for feature_map_index in (0, 1):
        plot_image(output[image_index, :, :, feature_map_index])
        plt.show()

reset_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, height, width, channels), dtype=tf.float32)
conv = tf.layers.conv2d(X, filters=2, kernel_size=7, strides=[2,2],
                        padding="SAME")

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    output = sess.run(conv, feed_dict={X: dataset})

plt.imshow(output[0, :, :, 1], cmap="gray") # plot 1st image's 2nd feature map
plt.show()


reset_graph()

filter_primes = np.array([2., 3., 5., 7., 11., 13.], dtype=np.float32)
x = tf.constant(np.arange(1, 13+1, dtype=np.float32).reshape([1, 1, 13, 1]))
filters = tf.constant(filter_primes.reshape(1, 6, 1, 1))

valid_conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, filters, strides=[1, 1, 5, 1], padding='VALID')
same_conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, filters, strides=[1, 1, 5, 1], padding='SAME')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print("VALID:\n", valid_conv.eval())
    print("SAME:\n", same_conv.eval())


print("VALID:")
print(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]).T.dot(filter_primes))
print(np.array([6,7,8,9,10,11]).T.dot(filter_primes))
print("SAME:")
print(np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5]).T.dot(filter_primes))
print(np.array([5,6,7,8,9,10]).T.dot(filter_primes))
print(np.array([10,11,12,13,0,0]).T.dot(filter_primes))


batch_size, height, width, channels = dataset.shape

filters = np.zeros(shape=(7, 7, channels, 2), dtype=np.float32)
filters[:, 3, :, 0] = 1  # vertical line
filters[3, :, :, 1] = 1  # horizontal line

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, height, width, channels))
max_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(X, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1],padding="VALID")

with tf.Session() as sess:
    output = sess.run(max_pool, feed_dict={X: dataset})

plt.imshow(output[0].astype(np.uint8))  # plot the output for the 1st image
plt.show()


plot_color_image(dataset[0])
save_fig("china_original")
plt.show()

plot_color_image(output[0])
save_fig("china_max_pool")
plt.show()

width = 28
channels = 1
n_inputs = height * width

conv1_fmaps = 32
conv1_ksize = 3
conv1_stride = 1
conv1_pad = "SAME"

conv2_fmaps = 64
conv2_ksize = 3
conv2_stride = 2
conv2_pad = "SAME"

pool3_fmaps = conv2_fmaps

n_fc1 = 64
n_outputs = 10

reset_graph()

with tf.name_scope("inputs"):
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_inputs], name="X")
    X_reshaped = tf.reshape(X, shape=[-1, height, width, channels])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name="y")

conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(X_reshaped, filters=conv1_fmaps, kernel_size=conv1_ksize,
                         strides=conv1_stride, padding=conv1_pad,
                         activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv1")
conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, filters=conv2_fmaps, kernel_size=conv2_ksize,
                         strides=conv2_stride, padding=conv2_pad,
                         activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv2")

with tf.name_scope("pool3"):
    pool3 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID")
    pool3_flat = tf.reshape(pool3, shape=[-1, pool3_fmaps * 7 * 7])

with tf.name_scope("fc1"):
    fc1 = tf.layers.dense(pool3_flat, n_fc1, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="fc1")

with tf.name_scope("output"):
    logits = tf.layers.dense(fc1, n_outputs, name="output")
    Y_proba = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="Y_proba")

with tf.name_scope("train"):
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.name_scope("eval"):
    correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

with tf.name_scope("init_and_save"):
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()


(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 28*28) / 255.0
X_test = X_test.astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 28*28) / 255.0
y_train = y_train.astype(np.int32)
y_test = y_test.astype(np.int32)
X_valid, X_train = X_train[:5000], X_train[5000:]
y_valid, y_train = y_train[:5000], y_train[5000:]

def shuffle_batch(X, y, batch_size):
    rnd_idx = np.random.permutation(len(X))
    n_batches = len(X) // batch_size
    for batch_idx in np.array_split(rnd_idx, n_batches):
        X_batch, y_batch = X[batch_idx], y[batch_idx]
        yield X_batch, y_batch

n_epochs = 10
batch_size = 100

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for X_batch, y_batch in shuffle_batch(X_train, y_train, batch_size):
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
        acc_batch = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
        acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_test, y: y_test})
        print(epoch, "Last batch accuracy:", acc_batch, "Test accuracy:", acc_test)

        save_path = saver.save(sess, "./my_mnist_model")
```

Everything runs fine until the very last section (with tf.Session() as sess:) where I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100, 784) for Tensor 'inputs/X:0', which has shape '(?, 1960)'
```

I have been reading the following related threads on Stack Overflow, most of which seem to have no resolution.

[ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (784,) for Tensor 'x:0', which has shape '(?, 784)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340597/valueerror-cannot-feed-value-of-shape-784-for-tensor-x0-which-has-shape)

[ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51444101/valueerror-cannot-feed-value-of-shape)

[Sketch_RNN , ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119832/sketch-rnn-valueerror-cannot-feed-value-of-shape)

Edit: I included some code that I thought was for a separate module, but was defining some of my parameters, namely height.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you are trying to give `x` a value with an incompatible shape. You don't show the value of `height` in your script, it would seem it has been set to `70`, instead of the expected `28`.

Comment: So the height parameter was defined earlier in the code, which I excluded and have edited my post to show now. It seems as though we are hard coding the height to be the same as one image (china.jpg), do I need to resize all images to be the same size as that initial height setting before it will work?

Comment: You can choose to scale the images within the neural network or before passing them as inputs, but you have to ensure that the value that you feed matches the expected input size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you jdehesa, I was able to simply put in a static parameter for the height and the program seems to run successfully.

```
height=28
```